# Extract Session ID from URL using Jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter, oracle-apex

I'm using jmeter to try and test a website. I'm currently having issues extracting information that is returned.

For instance I send a HTTP request to:

```
    https://intranet.company.com/Capps/f?p=101:1:
```

The website responds with:

```
   https://intranet.company.com/Capps/f?p=101:1:11016690116729:::::
```

The new string of numbers listed at the end of response is the session id that I must use to test other pages of the program. I've been trying to use a reg Ex extractor but I cannot seem to pull the number off the url. I am currently using jmeter 3.1

Regular Expressions I've tired:

```
f?p:101:1:([0-9]{16})::

f?p=([0-9]{1,3}):([0-9]{1,3}):([0-9]{16}):
```

And various similar expressions, but none have worked for me. If I set up the website with no session ids it will work, but the website is required to use session ids.

Thanks for any help you may provide,

Zwils0

Comment: When you say `The website responds with` do you mean it redirects to that URL? And how other settings on RegEx extractor look like?

Comment: Yes the website auto redirects. the other settings are: field to check = URL, reference name = sessionid, template = $1$, and match no = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to escape `?` sign as it is a meta-character and might be interpreted as repetition pattern
2. For some reason you are trying to extract 16-digit long integer while your id is 14-digit long

I would suggest the following Regular Expression Extractor configuration:

- Field to check: `URL`
- Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `id`
- Regular Expression: `f\?p=101:1:(\d+):`
- Template: `$1$`

Demo:

[image: Regular Expression Extractor APEX demo]

References:

- Apache JMeter: [Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about jmeter, but I guess it supports standard regex syntax. In your regular expressions, you are expecting a numeric session id with a constant length of 16. However, the session id is not necessary 16 digits long. In your own examples, it has 14 digits. If I check the session length on my oracle apex cloud account, it is 13 digits long.
I guess you cannot rely on its constant length, therefore, try to use something like this:

`f?p=([0-9]{1,3}):([0-9]{1,3}):([0-9]{10,16}):`

Or even this:

`f?p=([0-9]{1,3}):([0-9]{1,3}):([0-9]*):`

Also check out the following link and scroll down a bit. Guru Jeff Kemp already did something like this.

https://jeffkemponoracle.com/2011/10/07/googlebot-apex-session-ids-and-cookies/

Comment: Thanks, I was able to set the session id to 0, but I was still unable to extract the session id with the information you gave me. I can test the website without them for an initial run, but this website must allow for login with session ids and i would like to test that before the site needs to go live.

Answer (score 0):

Chris Muir covered it in his comprehensive post on configuring jmeter specifically for APEX. It's dated, but I'm pretty sure it still holds up.

c) sessionId Regular Expression Extractor

> f?p=([0-9]{1,3}):([0-9]{1,3}):([0-9]{16}):

http://one-size-doesnt-fit-all.blogspot.com.au/2010/05/configuring-apache-jmeter-for-apex.html

This appears to be what you've tried, but it seems like there may be other settings and considerations.